# Error when updating with NOT IN subquery

Tags: mysql

What is wrong in my query, why won't it execute?

```
UPDATE mbdb.pessoa
SET status = 4
WHERE id_pessoa NOT IN
    (SELECT id_pessoa
     FROM mbdb.pessoa mp
     INNER JOIN mbdb.funcionario mf ON mp.cpf = mf.cpf)
```

**Error Code:** 
You can't specify target table 'pessoa' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Either SELECT from the subquery again or better yet use a JOIN.

Comment: How could I make that using join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE mbdb.pessoa mp
LEFT JOIN mbdb.funcionario mf 
ON mp.cpf = mf.cpf
SET status = 4
WHERE funcionario.cpf IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will not allow you to UPDATE records and use the sub query that you are trying to use.

You can change your code to this.

```
UPDATE mbdb.pessoa m
SET m.status = 4
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mbdb.pessoa WHERE id_pessoa= m.id_pessoa)
```